# Can I avoid setting a bunch of variables to None just so I can use them later?

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm a bit new to Python, and I recently found myself writing code like this:

```
command = None
args = None
mode = None
query = None
short_args, long_args = None, None
if sys.argv[1] == '-s':
    # search mode
    command = sys.argv[2]
    query = sys.argv[3]
    mode = SEARCH
else:
    # normal mode
    command = sys.argv[1]
    args = sys.argv[2:]
    mode = NORMAL
    short_args, long_args = get_args(args)
```

Setting all those variables to None seems very boilerplate and wrong, and I'm sure there must be some cleaner way to do this?

I understand I could do something like:

```
command = sys.argv[2] if sys.argv[1] == 's' else None
```

but that seems a little over the top to do for ALL of them.

Or does this fall under "explicit is better than implicit," and I shouldn't worry about it too much?

Comment: Why aren't you using [argparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse)?

Comment: @JamesMills I just don't really need it.

Comment: I wouldn't like to use your CLI tool then :) *Usability*.

Comment: @JamesMills For a simple tool you don't need to bring in a complex library :) *Simple is better than complex.*

Comment: argparse is part of the python standard library; so I don't see it as *complex" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use such an assignment when needed, e.g. when it's useful to make the variable fall in the appropriate namespacw (scope).
Since there is no such thing as variable declaration, assignment also serves the purpose of indicating a type. 
Surely it's unnecessary to assign the variables beforehand if you are going to do it in any possible code path (if/else, as noted in the other answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that command would be set to something not `None` in your code, like in your example , you have both `if` statement as well as `else` and in both part you are setting the `command` variable to something, so you really do not need to set the `command` to None.

Same can be said about - `args` , `mode` .

Though it would be better to set the `None` for `short_args, long_args` , because they are not set in the `if` condition, and hence if you encounter a code that tries to use them, and if they were not defined you would get `NameError`.